# Customizing Stripe Pay Button

Tags: javascript, django, stripe-payments

I have added a stripe pay button using the following javascript:

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
ta-key="{{ key }}"
data-description="Select"
data-amount="10000"
data-locale="auto">
</script>
```

I got the pay button but i can't customize it.If anyone can refer me any post of links please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own button and customize it, you can do a custom integration of legacy Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/legacy-checkout#integration-custom

However you shouldn't be using legacy Checkout at all as it's been deprecated. Instead you should look into using new Checkout instead, which is easier to implement and a better experience for your users: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout